# Material UI button is not working on mobile

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a `material-ui` button as a link to an exterior page. When I click the button on my desktop it works perfectly fine and opens a new tab but when I try to click it on my phone (Android but I tried Iphone as well) nothing happens. The button in question is the first one with the class name of 'page'.

```
const SwipeButtons = (props) => {
    
    return (
        <div className='swipe-buttons'>
            <Button  className='page' startIcon={<PageviewIcon/>} style={{color: 'rgb(38, 64, 179)'}} href={`${props.url}`} target='_blank'>
                View Profile
            </Button>
   
                
            <Button className='fav' startIcon={<FavoriteIcon/>} style={{color: '#ef32d9'}}>
                    Like
            </Button>
          
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code in `stackbiltz` or `sandbox`?